# Tomcat está configurado pelo Eclipse para subir na porta 8085 mas só abre na 8080

Tags: jsf, xml, eclipse, jsf-2.2, tomcat

Galera, ao configurar o Tomcat no eclipse ele deu o erro dizendo que as portas padrões (8005,8080,8009) estavam ocupadas, mudei as portas e rodei o programa, só que no Google Chrome quando coloco localhost:8080 ele abre mesmo não estando configurado para essa porta!!! Mas quando coloco localhost:8085 que são as portas "abertas" segundo o eclipse e que eu salvei na conexão do server o browser da 404.

[image: localhost:8080]

[image: chamando o arquivo diretamente]

[image: chamando o localhost:8085]

Como faço pra ficar só na 8080? Já desinstalei o Tomcat e instalei uma versão anterior e ficou a mesma coisa. Já parei e reiniciei ele pelos Serviços mas sem sucesso. Consigo entrar de manager na 8080 normal. Parece até que ele tá duplicado, sei lá.

Tô aprendendo JSF rodando no Windows 10.

Comment: Nunca usei tomcat, por isso respondendo em comentário mas me parece que o vhost do servidor apache está sobre a mesma porta do tomcat e portanto quanto tenta trocar dá o erro.Tente trocar o apache para a porta 8081.Segue esses passos também para descobrir qual programa está alocando a porta https://engdanielsantos.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/como-indentificar-processos-servios-ou-aplicaes-que-esto-trabalhando-numa-determinada-porta-do-windows/

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário Rafael. Acredito ter entendido o "problema", quando eu subo o Tomcat pelo Eclipse e jogo localhost:8080 no navegador e dá 404 é o Tomcat falando que está tudo ok (lá no final aparece Apache Tomcat 9.0, pelo que vi ele não configura aquela tela de boas vindas subindo pelo Eclipse ele inicia o Tomcat cru, puro. Esse é o motivo de meu .jsp e o xhtml aparecer pelo navegador diretamente. As situações eram duas: Primeira, eu tava dando run no Eclipse (não se pode fazer isso). A segunda era que eu estava levantando o Tomcat pelo ícone da bandeja,isso só se faz para dar manage

Comment: Então, resolveu ?

Comment: Sim, resolvi. Está tudo certo agora.